# Including a file in another directory

Tags: php, include

I tried to include a file in another directory using php. There are two directories

Name of first directory : 'includes' and it contains a file called sample.php

Name of second directory : 'core' and it contains main.php

I need to include the main.php file in sample.php. I used the following but it still shows the warning saying no such file exists. But the file is live there.

```
include '../main.php';
```

So what do I do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
include dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'core'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'main.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have said that `main.php` lives in `core`. Then:

```
include '../core/main.php';
```